# "No result" when trying to retrieve names from database

Tags: php, database, sql-insert

Okay, so as you can see, I made a form. If I put in a name and surname and try to display it afterwards it works, but it goes wrong when I am trying to 'post' it to the database and retrieve it. It gives me a "no result". Since I'm fairly new to this, I don't know what I did wrong. Anyone seeing the problem here?

```
    //Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    //Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }


    echo "<form action='' method='post'>
    Naam: <input type='text' name='name'><br>
    Achternaam: <input type='text' name='surname'><br>
    <input type='submit'>
    </form>";

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $surname = $_POST["surname"];

    //insert name
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Namen
    VALUES ($name, $surname)";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);


    if(!$result){
     echo "fout ".mysql_error();   

    }

    $sql = "SELECT Voornaam, Achternaam FROM Namen";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    echo "<table border='1px'>";
    echo "<th>Naam</th>";
    echo "<th>Achternaam</th>";
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr><td>" .$row["Voornaam"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["Achternaam"] . "</td></tr>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values' variables `VALUES ($name, $surname)` must be encapsulated inside quotes, since we are (*more than likely*) dealing with strings.

Change it to `VALUES ('$name', '$surname')`

You're also mixing (*they don't mix together*) MySQL APIs with `echo "fout ".mysql_error();` which needs to be changed to `echo "fout ".mysqli_error($conn);` to give you the actual error(s) found.

Also, your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).
Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

You should also consider wrapping your code (*or the one you wish to execute*) inside a conditional statement based on a named submit button.

I.e.:

```
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>
```

then doing

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){...}
```

the `{...}` being your initial query, and/or the entire (*or portion of*) of your PHP/SQL  code.